# how to get a value from my controller in my directive

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

so i am using angular js and i have got a controller and a directive.

```
directive = ->
    scope:
        items: "=mkTagsInput"
    link: (scope, element, attributes, controller) ->
        $(element[0]).tagsinput()
        $(element[0]).tagsinput('input').typeahead
            name: "list"
            local: scope.items
```

well this is my directive (in coffescript) so far.

```
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" mk-tags-input="labels" />
```

This is the way i am calling the directive. The problem is that I initialize the labels array with []. and I also make an Ajax request to load the data, but the directive seems to be loaded to early, so that in scope.items is always [] as the value.

Any idea how i can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create a watch over the directive scope `items`. In this way when the items collection is updated you would get notification

```
scope.$watch('items',function(newValue,oldValue) {
  if(newValue) {
      //Your item conllection is in newValue
   }
});
```

Basically a watch is triggered any time to reference to the items collection is changed. If you are on angularjs 1.2.0 RC then also look for method `watchCollection` on scope. See documentation here http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope